# Configure subdomain godaddy and use an existing CERT

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, subdomain

I just created a subdomain ony my domain named:

```
profile.cv.hsoto.me
```

However, when I try to access it, I get a warning:

[image]

I'm not sure how to fix this. My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?moonlightbeachclub\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

A friend of mine configured this for me, so I do not really know much about if there's a problem there. Is there a way to use my main SSL on my subdomains as well?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your certificate needs to be valid for every domain you are serving.  This might be done through a wildcard, by setting up alternative names (SAN).

Comment: Where do I do that on cpanel?

Comment: You don't do that on cpanel. Its a setting in the certificate itself - it comes from the CA that issued the certificate. If you need a wildcard or SAN cert, you need to actually get one issued.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you asked `Where do I do that on cpanel?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use one SSL certificate across subdomains, it must be a [wildcard SSL certificate](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/567/what-is-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate), or specifically enumerate the subdomains for which it is valid with SAN.  That might not be what you bought.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, since it is the correct answer.